# Mockito - Return mocked object everytime a method is called

Tags: junit, mockito

I am trying to write a unit test for a piece of code I am writing using Mockito.

I need to return a mocked object whenever any class of a given type calls a certain method.

I was thinking something like the following but I can't seem to get it working.

```
    Mockito.when(Mockito.any((MyObject.class).myMethod(Mockito.anyString()))).thenReturn(mockedObject);
```

Basically any time any instance of MyObject calls it's myMethod() method I want to return a mockedObject.

Any know it this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mockito doesn't work this way. With Mockito you'll create a mock instance and pass it to the tested client code of the mock.

```
MyObject mo = mock(MyObject.class);

@Before public void init() {
    // inject mo to the tested code
}

@Test public void ensure_client_code_notify_my_object() {
    // given
    when(mo.myMethod(anyString()))).thenReturn(anotherMock);

    // when
    client.theTestedAPI();

    // then
    // verify(...)....
    // assertThat(...)....
```

Please note that a mock returning a mock is usually not a good sign regarding the design of the production code. It shows sign of coupling and especially it means this code is breaking *the law of Demeter*.

To improve *separation of concerns* and to avoid breaking the *law of Demeter*, you definitely should follow the *tell, don't ask* principle.

A very good read would be this book [Growing Object Oriented Software Guided by Tests](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503627).

HTH

Comment: Thanks for that. Yep the code I have to write ties in with a legacy code base. Tightly coupled is not the word for it.